# ViewPager not displaying correct Image

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I have 3 pages in my app that i traverse by doing the sliding motion on the screen.

The whole application has only 1x ImageView shared by 3 pages/fragments.
Each have their own image.

The problem comes in when i swipe to each of these pages. When swiping from Page 1 -> 2 -> 3 and back to 2 -> 1 -> 2 and finally back to 1, the ImageView in page 1 shows the ImageView from page 2 instead. I do not understand why this occurs even when the various logs i put in clearly shows that i am at the correct page and the correct functions are called.

I have replaced the code in this question with a shorter version but basically showcases the same problems too. These were the code that i referenced from a website that i cannot remember when searching for how to do swiping of multiple pages.

The zip file of this project is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18514981/Swiping.zip)

Here's the code for MainActivity.java,

```
package com.example.swiping;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    static final int NUM_PAGE = 3;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    public static ViewPager mViewPager;
    static ImageView ImgView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); //This is from the activity_main.xml's one and only ViewPager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show x number of pages.
            return NUM_PAGE;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }//SectionsPagerAdapter

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView
        (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate
                    (R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText
            (Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            ImgView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            Log.i("Swiping", "Current Item is " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position)
                {   
                    Log.i("Swiping", "Current Item is " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

                    if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0)
                    {
                        ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qnmark));
                    }
                    else if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1)
                    {
                        ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.genieus));
                    }
                    else if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2)
                    {
                        ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.community));
                    }
                }
            });//setOnPageChangeListener

            return rootView;
        }//onCreateView
    }//PlaceholderFragment

}//MainActivity
```

Comment: in one of my projects i have faced this problem ....if you are still working  on it  let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing "setOnPageChangeListener()" and made use of the bundle instead. 
Here's the code:

```
package com.example.swiping;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    static final int NUM_PAGE = 3;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    public static ViewPager mViewPager;
    static ImageView ImgView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); //This is from the activity_main.xml's one and only ViewPager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show x number of pages.
            return NUM_PAGE;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }//SectionsPagerAdapter

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView
        (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate
                    (R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();

            if( bundle != null )
            {
                int PageNum = bundle.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(PageNum));

                ImgView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                if(PageNum == 1)
                {
                    ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qnmark));
                }
                else if(PageNum == 2)
                {
                    ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.genieus));
                }
                else if(PageNum == 3)
                {
                    ImgView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.community));
                }

            }

            return rootView;
        }//onCreateView
    }//PlaceholderFragment

}//MainActivity
```

Credits goes to watching one of the Android tutorial videos from CodingBits [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4Qyhh9KKlI) on implementing ViewPager. Apparently, it is more stable to decide what images and text to be displayed rather than changing them on the fly whenever a page is changed.

My observations from the video tutorial is that every time a fragment is created in getItem(), a bundle containing what image to show and description to use (using some form of id) is put into the bundle. The bundle is then added into the fragment.

At onCreateView(), the bundle is checked for null first before retrieving it's values. These values are then used to set the ImageView and the Text description.

However, i am still curious as to why setOnPageChangeListener() did not work properly or could be i am not using it correctly. If anybody can provide me with an explanation, i would really appreciate it.